# "Comparison method violates general contract " while sorting multi dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I am sorting a 2-d array using custom comparator and getting the following error in some cases :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
> at line 781, java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeLo
> at line 518, java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt
> at line 448, java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse
> at line 245, java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort
> at line 1442, java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort

Below is the code that is throwing this error :

```
class Solution {
    public int[][] merge(int[][] intervals) {
        Arrays.sort(intervals, new SortComparator());
    }
}

class SortComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {
    public int compare(int []a, int []b) {
        if(a[0] < b[0]) {
            return -1;
        } else if(a[0] > b[0]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if(a[1] < b[1]) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although when I am using the below implementation of `SortComparator` class everything works fine :

```
class SortComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {
    public int compare(int []a, int []b) {
        if(a[0] < b[0]) {
            return -1;
        } else if(a[0] > b[0]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if(a[1] < b[1]) {
                return -1;
            } else if(a[1]> b[1]) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I know because of what reason first implementation of `SortComparator` is throwing error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your first `SortComparator` implementation can never return `0`.

Therefore `SortComparator.compare(a, a)` cannot ever return `0` as it is required to do by "the general contract" for `Comparator` implementations.

In fact, `SortComparator.compare(a, a)` will return `1`.

---

The actual contract is in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).  What it says is:

> The notation `sgn(expression)` designates<sup>1</sup> the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.
>
> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.  (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception if and only if `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)
>
> [...]

The only way that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` can be true when `x` and `y` are the same object is if `-sgn(compare(x, x))` is zero for all `x`.

---

<sup>1 - Nitpick: I think they should have used the word "denotes" rather than "designates" here.</sup>

Comment: Okay..so you mean to say it is always necessary to return 0 in case both values are same . Is it not okay if I return 1 in equal case as well.

Comment: It is NOT ok to return 1 in the equal case.

Comment: @StephenC The last line is a bit tricky, thanks for the explanation, I think that should also need to add  in documentation (IMHO).

Comment: Feel free to submit a bug report.  (But a better suggestion would be to suggest that they explain the comparator contract in layman's terms in the Java Tutorial.)